# Summing a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, sum, tuples

I have a list of tuples containing intergers.

```
[(123,123,123),(123,123,123),(123,123,123)]
```

I want to get the sum of all the second values of the list eg;

```
[(_,123,_),(_,123,_),(_,123,_)]
```

123 + 123 + 123

I think i should be using fold but im not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract second value from the list of tuple list to get a new list and then sum the new list.

```
Prelude> let a = [(123,123,123),(123,123,123),(123,123,123)]
Prelude> sum [i | (_,i,_) <- a]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. I tried this and it seems to work:

```
sumSecondTuple list = foldl (\acc (x, y, z) -> (+) y acc) 0 list
```

This says, start with a value of 0, then add the accumulated value to the `y` value in the tuple `(x, y, z)` for all items in `list`.

Comment: What is the value acc in the anonymous function?

Comment: It's the accumulator. When you use `foldl`, it starts with some value, and keeps a running total. In this case, we start with 0 (that's the 0 you see in the function declaration). On each step, it calls the anonymous function with the value accumulated so far, and the next element of the list as parameters. So `acc` is the value accumulated so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of lenses (importing `Control.Lens`) one solution is

```
sumsnds = sum . toListOf (traverse . _2)
```

This will **sum** the values in the **list** you get when you **traverse** a list of tuples and pick out the **second** value in each tuple.